# How to select all strings the containing " n'th\product_table " from a column, in SQL using LIKE?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-like

How to select all strings the containing the substring  "***n'th\product_table***"  from a column, in SQL using LIKE?

Example:-
1)There is a table1 with following data

```
column1  
_ _    
"from n'th\product_table of period"  
"from n'th\product$table of period"  
"for of n'th\groduct$table of people"     
"to n'th\product_table of classes"  
"change n'th\producttable of record" 
"correct n'thproduct_table of value"
```

Can anyone give an SQL query that uses LIKE operator gives the result of all strings containing the substring "***n'th\product_table***"

Expected result

```
column1  
_ _    
"from n'th\product_table of period"
"to n'th\product_table of classes"
```

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be nice to provide accurate answer and do not waste time to guess.

Comment: `where col like '%n''th\product_table%'`

Comment: @TonyAndrews but it will also select the row from ***n'th\product$table of period*** which is not meant to happen

Comment: '%n''th\product\\_table%'

Comment: @mnv but it will also select the row ***for of n'th\groduct$table of people*** which is not meant to happen

Comment: I see - if only you had mentioned what the problem was originally i.e. underscore character being treated as wild!  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 'from n\'th\\product_table of period' AS c
    UNION 
    SELECT 'from n\'th\\product$table of period'
) t
WHERE c LIKE '%n\'th\\\\product\_table%'
```

Result is

```
"from n'th\product_table of period"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an escape character to make the underscore mean underscore:

```
where col like '%n''th\\product\_table%' escape '\'
```

Note that the escape character needs to be used before the actual '\' in the string as well as the '_':

```
where col like '%n''th\\product\_table%' escape '\'
                      ^        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This method uses REGEXP_LIKE().  You just have to escape the special characters `'` and `\` to make them literal:

```
SQL> with tbl(str) as (
     select 'from n''th\product_table of period' from dual union
     select 'from n''th\product$table of period'   from dual union
     select 'for of n''th\groduct$table of people'  from dual union
     select 'to n''th\product_table of classes'   from dual union
     select 'change n''th\producttable of record'  from dual union
     select 'correct n''thproduct_table of value' from dual
   )
   select str
   from tbl
   where regexp_like(str, '.*n''th\\product_table.*');

STR
-----------------------------------
from n'th\product_table of period
to n'th\product_table of classes

SQL>
```